# Does archiving files reduces number of inode

Tags: linux, centos, inode

I read a couple of articles about Linux inode and understand that each file created always have a corresponding inode number. Since one of our servers is using ext4 there is no way to increase the inode to an already running production server.

There are two solutions we can do one is to delete older files and the other is to transfer older files to another server and archive it.
My question now is if I archive and compress the files and then move it to another server. On the archive server how many inode number will be assigned to the compressed file I just transferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collecting multiple files in a single archive file reduces inode consumption to that required to handle that file. The number of blocks used is not correspondingly guaranteed to be reduced (but it usually will be regardless).

Comment: Thanks for answering, so if I have 3 files which ideally should have 3 inode numbers. Once I archive and compress the file it will have less than 3 inode or ideally 1 inode number assigned to the archive file and the previous 3 inode numbers are freed up. Am I right in this assumption?

Comment: The inodes will only be freed up if the files are removed, of course.

Comment: ok, i just need to clarify this ... back on my original question. If i have 3 files and compressed/archived in Server A then transferred it to Server B. On Server B the OS will assign 4 inode number to the archived file I just transferred or just 1 inode?

Comment: Just the one, since there's just the one file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes, it increases but only by one(inode) - the archive itself.
Now, you mentioned that archiving takes place on the stand-alone(backup-server) side...
If it's coresponding to production capacity you probably still have to make shure not to restore more than one instance or state of your "archive"

Checking `ulimit && df -i` you can see

```
unlimited
   IFree IUse%
  999961    1%
 1006760    1%
14853576    3%
```

Which is part of my state now.
And you can check the amount of unarchived\restored inodes in place:

*Please, be aware of calculation time, may not be the fastest one-liner:

```
ls -d1 "./" | while read i; do echo -en "$i\t"; find "$i" -name "*" | wc -l; done;
```